# JavaScript: HTML Image Source From Blob String Is Not Working

Tags: javascript

Am trying to set img src in JavaScript from a BLOB that is returned to JavaScript as a string (ex: **�PNG  IHDR��csRGB���IDATHKݖMJ�@��r=**) but it is not working.

The following example is a simulation for the issue, where for IMG 1 it works as it's dealing directly with the BLOB object, however if I try to get the string (e.target.result) form the BLOB and assign to IMG 2 then it is not working:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.SomeURL.com/SomeImage.png");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function(r){

    // IMG 1 WORKS FINE:
    document.getElementById('img1').src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(this.response);
    
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) {
        
        // IMG 2 IS NOT WORKING WITH ANY OF THESE:
        document.getElementById('img2').src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob([e.target.result], {type:'image/png'}));
        document.getElementById('img2').src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(e.target.result)], {type:'image/png'}));
            
    };

    fr.readAsText(this.response);
   
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Reading a response stream as a string means interpreting the bytes as Unicode, and the bytes in an image may not be valid Unicode sequences.

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense. You get a `Blob` from XHR then you turn that into a `string` to convert it back to a `Blob`.
Just use that Blob directly.
Aldo, you could use `fetch` instead of xhr.

Comment: @Xion: this is for simulation only, my case is that am receiving the image as BLOB string.